# Running grunt server with php

Tags: php, angularjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I have to expand an WebApp and want to use the yeomann Angular-Fullstack generator. So far so good. The first part of the APP was written in Angular with an PHP Backend. When developing and runing "grunt Serve" the server does not seem to run PHP files.

I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express) module php-Express. It adds php support to the express server. Is that the right one? How do I install it?

Comment: Since you found it on NPM you'll want to install it with NPM.

Comment: So I install it and then, how do I insert it into my project? I have the folder already in node-modules. Is it then installed directly or do i have to configure it somewhere? I dont get it...

Comment: You need to take some time to read the documentation and understand how to work with the package.